# Self-destructive Button inside Column

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

How to create a `Button` which will be displayed only when the value of some global FrontEnd setting is `False` and will self-destruct with entire row of the `Column` after pressing it setting this value to `True`?

I need something like this:

```
Column[{"Item 1", "Item 2", 
  Dynamic[If[
    Last@Last@Options[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences"] === False, 
    Button["Press me!", 
     SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences" -> True]], 
    Sequence @@ {}]]}]
```

But with this code the `Button` does not disappear after pressing it. Is it possible to make it self-destructive?

---

The final solution based on ideas by [belisarius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353410/belisarius) and [mikuszefski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/803359/mikuszefski):

```
PreemptProtect[SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences" -> False];
   b = True];

Dynamic[Column[
  Join[{"Item 1", "Item 2"}, 
   If[Last@Last@Options[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences"] === False &&
      b == True, {Button[
      Pane[Style[
        "This FrontEnd uses shared preferences file. Press this \
button to set FrontEnd to use versioned preferences file (all the \
FrontEnd settings will be reset to defaults).", Red], 300], 
      AbortProtect[
       SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences" -> True]; 
       b = False]]}, {}]], Alignment -> Center], 
 Initialization :> 
  If[! Last@Last@Options[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences"], b = True,
    b = False]]
```

The key points are:

- introducing additional `Dynamic` variable `b` and binding it with the value of `Options[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences"]`,
- wrapping entire `Column` construct
  with `Dynamic` instead of using
  `Dynamic` inside `Column`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps

```
PreemptProtect[SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences" -> False]; b = True]; 

Column[{"Item 1", "Item 2", Dynamic[
   If[Last@Last@Options[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences"]===False && b == True, 
    Button["Here!", SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences"->True];b=False], 
   "Done"]]}]
```

**Edit**

Answering your comment. Please try the following. Encompassing the `Column[ ]` with `Dynamic[ ]` allows resizing it:

```
PreemptProtect[SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences" -> False]; b = True]; 
Dynamic[
  Column[{
   "Item 1", 
   "Item 2",
   If[Last@Last@Options[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences"] === False && b == True, 
    Button["Press me!", SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences" -> True]; b=False], 
    Sequence @@ {}]}]]
```

Comment: I wish to completely destruct the entire row of the column after pressing the button.

Comment: @Alexey Ohhh sorry, I misunderstood. Now I understand the `Sequence@@{}` :)

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, dunno if I get it right, but maybe this:

x = True;

Dynamic[Column[{Button["reset", x = True], 
   If[x, Button["Press me", x = False]]}]
 ]

Comment: With this code the button disappears but a white space is left on where it was. I wish the corresponding row of the `Column` to completely disappear.

Comment: It seems that your version can be improved just by adding `Sequence @@ {}` as the third argument of `If`.

Comment: @Alexey try x = True;Dynamic[If[x, 
  Column[{Button["reset", x = True], Button["Press me", x = False]}], 
  Column[{Button["reset", x = True]}]]] (of course then you have two versions of the code differing by the existence or not of the second button, but they can be constructed on the fly)

Comment: This double code can be avoided by:

x = True;
Dynamic[
 Column[Join[{"Some Stuff", Button["reset", x = True]}, 
   If[x, { Button["Press me", x = False]}, {}]]
  ]
 ]

as Join[] does not act on empty Lists.